# How to select most important features? Feature Engineering

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, data-science, feature-extraction, hierarchical-clustering

I used the function for gower distance from this link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/gower-distance-4python/files/. My data (`df`) is such that each row is a trade, and each of the columns are features. Since it contains a lot of categorical data, I then converted the data using gower distance to measure "similarity"... I hope this is correct (as below..):

```
D = gower_distances(df)
distArray = ssd.squareform(D)
hierarchal_cluster=scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage(distArray, method='ward', metric='euclidean', optimal_ordering=False)
```

I then plot the hierarchical_cluster from above into a dendogram:

```
plt.title('Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram (truncated)')
plt.xlabel('sample index or (cluster size)')
plt.ylabel('distance')

dendrogram(
    hierarchal_cluster,
    truncate_mode='lastp',  # show only the last p merged clusters
    p=15,  # show only the last p merged clusters
    leaf_rotation=90.,
    leaf_font_size=12.,
    show_contracted=True  # to get a distribution impression in truncated branches
)
```

I cannot show it, since I do not have enough  privilege points, but on the dendogram I can see separate colors.
What is the main discriminator separating them?
How can I find this out?
How can I use PCA to extract useful features?
Do I pass my 'hierarchal_cluster' into a PCA function?
Something like the below..?

```
pca = PCA().fit(hierarchal_cluster.T)
plt.plot(np.arange(1,len(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)+1,1),pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum())
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you do know that PCA works only for continuous data? Since you mentioned, there are many categorical features. From what you have written, it occurs that you got mixed data.

A common practice when dealing with mixed data is to separate the continuous and categorical features/variables. Then find the Euclidean distance between data points for continuous (or numerical) features and Hamming distance for the categorical features [1].

This will enable you to find similarity between continuous and categorical feature separately. Now, while you are at this, apply PCA on the continuous variables to extract important features. And apply `Multiple Correspondence Analysis` [MCA](https://pypi.org/project/mca/) on the categorical features. Thereafter, you can combine the obtained relevant features together, and apply any clustering algorithm.

So essentially, I'm suggesting feature selection/feature extraction before clustering.

[1] Huang, Z., 1998. Extensions to the k-means algorithm for clustering large data sets with categorical values. Data mining and knowledge discovery, 2(3), pp.283-304.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the documentation of scipy on the matter of Ward linkage:

> Methods ‘centroid’, ‘median’ and ‘ward’ are correctly defined only if Euclidean pairwise metric is used. If y is passed as precomputed pairwise distances, then it is a user responsibility to assure that these distances are in fact Euclidean, otherwise the produced result will be incorrect.

So you can't use Ward linkage with Gower!

Comment: In this tutorial https://medium.com/@anastasia.reusova/hierarchical-clustering-on-categorical-data-in-r-a27e578f2995 they pass a gower matrix for hierarchal clustering. Since the dendogram in python needs to contain doubles how do i convert my gower matrix into a form i can use for hierachcal clustering?

Comment: The blog post clearly states it was a first attempt, not the "right" way to do things. But they use complete linkage, which is fine to use with Gower. And Gower does return doubles...